Android app not asking for permission, automatically denies it
I am trying to upgrade an old app, designed for Android 5, and I am a bit lost.
The application needs storage permission to read a JSON file from a location selected by user and write images (screenshots taken inside the app using screenshotty https://github.com/bolteu/screenshotty)
The problem is, on Android up to 10, I get a prompt asking me to allow storage access.
On newer versions (tried on 13 and 14), it goes directly into dening the permission and I cannot save any screenshot.
I do however, get to acces the storage and read the JSON file.
I upgraded gradle, dependencies and all to met Google Play requirements as of August this year:
buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
compileSdk 34
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 34

My permission list:
<!-- Scoped Storage Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

<!-- Only include this if necessary for broad file access -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> -->

MainActivity
private var screenshotManager: ScreenshotManager? = null
private val REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 1

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION
        )
    }
    else
    {
        hasStoragePermission = true
    }

    screenshotManager = ScreenshotManagerBuilder(this)
        .withPermissionRequestCode(888) //optional, 888 is the default
        .build()
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, 
                                        permissions: Array<out String>, 
                                        grantResults: IntArray) 
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION)
    {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            hasStoragePermission = true
        }
        else
        {
            // I get this all the time on newer Android versions
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

The code is kinda messy but it partially works.
Any suggestions on what am I missing? I kept trying different approaches but I keep running around in circles, it would seem.

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are not used on modern versions of Android. So, you will not get permission prompts.

This is how I solved it, in case anyone needs it:
<!-- Scoped Storage Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />

<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"   
</application>


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity()
{
    private val permissionRequestCode = 1001
    private var hasStoragePermissionLowAPIs: Boolean? = false
    private var hasCaptureingPermission: Boolean? = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Check for storage permissions (for Android 5 to 9)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        {
            if (!hasStoragePermissions())
            {
                requestStoragePermissions()
            }
            else
            {
                println("savePictureToPicturesDirectory")
                hasStoragePermissionLowAPIs = true
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // For Android 10 and above
            hasStoragePermissionLowAPIs = true
        }
    }

    private fun hasStoragePermissions(): Boolean
    {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    // Request storage permissions (for Android 5 to 9)
    private fun requestStoragePermissions()
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            permissionRequestCode
        )
    }

    // Handle permission request result
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == permissionRequestCode)
        {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                hasStoragePermissionLowAPIs = true
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Storage permission denied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}


Storage has change a lot since Android 5 I suggest you go through the documentation again on how to work with files and such.
Android 11+ WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE does not do anything so you must use the newer scoped/shared storage
this also means that what you currently do with reading a json file and reading where the user wants to store images might not work anymore.

Thanks. The JSON part works just fine and that surprised me as I didn't expect it to. The image part does not.

In my app I use the following code

write in shared storage
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)
    // other code
    //
    setExportCsvSearchActivityResultLauncher()


 fun setExportCsvSearchActivityResultLauncher() {
 // You can do the assignment inside onAttach or onCreate, i.e, before the activity is displayed
 exportCsvSearchActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
     ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
     object : ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult?> {
         override fun onActivityResult(result: ActivityResult?) {
             if (result!!.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 // There are no request codes
                 val resultData = result.data
                 // doSomeOperations();
                 csvTreeUri = null
                 //
                 if (resultData != null) {
                     csvTreeUri = Objects.requireNonNull(resultData).data
                     val outputFolder = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, csvTreeUri!!)
                     //
                     if ((isStoragePermissionGranted) || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU))
                     // if the version code >= TIRAMISU (version 33 = Android 13)
                     // you don't need to ask for StoragePermission
                     {
                         Images.exporttoCsv(context, realm)
                         // other code
                         assert(outputFolder != null)
                         //
                         try {
                             copyFileFromInternalToSharedStorage(
                                 context,
                                 outputFolder!!,
                                 "images.csv"
                             )
             // other code
                         } catch (e: IOException) {
                             e.printStackTrace()
                         }
                         //
                     }
                     // view the fragment settings initializing MenuSettingsFragment (FragmentTransaction
                     // switch between Fragments).
                     // other code
                 }
             }
         }
     })
 }



and
    @Throws(IOException::class)
@JvmStatic
fun copyFileFromInternalToSharedStorage(context:Context, outputFolder: DocumentFile, destFileName: String?) {
    val sourceStream: InputStream = context.openFileInput(destFileName)
    val documentFileNewFile = outputFolder.createFile("text/csv", destFileName!!)!!
    val destStream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(
        documentFileNewFile.uri
    )
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var read: Int
    while (sourceStream.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
        destStream!!.write(buffer, 0, read)
    }
    destStream?.close()
    sourceStream.close()
}


read from shared storage
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     // other
     setActivityResultLauncher()
 // other

/**
  * Called when the user taps the image search button.
  *
  * @param v view of tapped button
  */
 fun imageSearch(v: View) {
     // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the intent to choose a file via the system's file
     // browser.
     val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
     // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
     // file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
     // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
     // If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
     // To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
     // it would be "*/*".
     intent.type = "image/*"
     /*  the instructions of the button */
     imageSearchActivityResultLauncher!!.launch(intent)
 }

 fun setActivityResultLauncher() {
     // You can do the assignment inside onAttach or onCreate, i.e, before the activity is displayed
     imageSearchActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
         ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
         object : ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult?> {
             override fun onActivityResult(result: ActivityResult?) {
                 if (result!!.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                     // There are no request codes
                     val resultData = result.data
                     // doSomeOperations();
                     var uri: Uri? = null
                     var stringUri: String? = null
                     filePath = getString(R.string.non_trovato)
                     //
                     val immD = findViewById<View>(R.id.imageDescription) as EditText
                     //
                     if (resultData != null) {
                         uri = Objects.requireNonNull(resultData).data
                         //
                         try {
                             filePath = copyFileFromSharedToInternalStorageAndGetPath(context, uri!!)
                         } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
                             e.printStackTrace()
                         }
                         //
                         val takeFlags =
                             resultData.flags and Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                         context.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                             uri!!,
                             takeFlags
                         )
                         // other
                     }
                 }
             }
         })
 }

 fun copyFileFromSharedToInternalStorageAndGetPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
     // The query, because it only applies to a single document, returns only
     // one row. There's no need to filter, sort, or select fields,
     // because we want all fields for one document.
     val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
         uri, null, null, null, null, null)
     var displayName: String? = null
     cursor?.use {
         // moveToFirst() returns false if the cursor has 0 rows. Very handy for
         // "if there's anything to look at, look at it" conditionals.
         if (it.moveToFirst()) {
             // Note it's called "Display Name". This is
             // provider-specific, and might not necessarily be the file name.
             val myCursorColumnIndex = it.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
             displayName =
                 it.getString(myCursorColumnIndex)
         }
     }
     //
     val rootPath = context.filesDir.absolutePath
     if (displayName != null)
     {
         copyFileFromSharedToInternalStorage(context, uri, displayName)
         return rootPath+"/"+displayName
     }
     return null
 }

 fun copyFileFromSharedToInternalStorage(context:Context, sourceUri: Uri?, destFileName: String?) {
     val sourceStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(sourceUri!!)
     val destStream = context.openFileOutput(destFileName, AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)
     val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
     var read: Int
     while (sourceStream!!.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
         destStream.write(buffer, 0, read)
     }
     destStream.close()
     sourceStream.close()
 }



